# Удалить строку из DataGridView(C#)

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview

Есть DataGridView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На кнопку delete должно происходить удаление выделенной в DataGridView строки.
Вопрос: какой метод необходимо вызвать для удаления выделенной строки?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, как эта строка туда попадает? Есть ли привязка данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.имя_вашего_gridView.SelectedRows)
    {
        имя_вашего_gridView.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: A как из DataSet удалить данную строку?

Comment: @bsuart, поищите информацию [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx).